# i am unable to download and upload app on my ipad mini ,! help me out

Tags: ipad

[image]

what should i do to fix this? it is happening past twodays. iam from India, please help me out .

Answer (score 1):

iTunes has just changed their T&C (Therms and Conditions).

You will have to first accept those to continue.

I just tried and it downloads the Candy Crash Saga.

Log out and back in.

Comment: i have accepted t&c . but still cant download and update apps . i even logged out and signed in again., help me out with this problem.,